# getting data from website using Android

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm trying to get data from from 
[Stations Bike](https://yelo.agglo-larochelle.fr/stations?address=&velos=true)

I try to take the positions of all stations available in the city using the website above

and then get Latitude & Longitude to show them into a map activity .

After having analyzed the web page I have not found a way to do that such as an RSS feed or a file in JSON format

My Question is how to get data from the map in the website using Android.

Thank you.

Comment: Well without an available API to get that info, you'll have to parse it out of the html which may or may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find json usage in the [Stations Bike](https://yelo.agglo-larochelle.fr/stations?address=&velos=true), I found an interesting json data using the following link:

```
https://yelo.agglo-larochelle.fr/stations?p_p_id=yeloStationsResult_WAR_cdalarochelleportlets&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=exclusive&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_yeloStationsResult_WAR_cdalarochelleportlets_action=nextBus&busStationId=2
```

It give us json data about a specific station with its longitude and latitude. This could be their api. But I can't make sure that.

Remember to adhere to their website tos.